# Изменить дизайн терминала в VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]на данный момент результат запуска py файла выглядит таким образом, хотелось бы убрать строчку с cd

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "убрать строчку с cd"?

Comment: под "убрать строчку с cd" я имел ввиду убрать видимый вызов этих команд.